# What's CPU Factor?

Tags: linux, unix, time, cpu, process

I know this is very vague, but I don't have a lot of information.

There is an internal company program I use that prints out timing statistics after it runs, such as Wall clock time, User time, System time, CPU Model, and CPU Speed. One of these statistics is called "CPU Factor."

What could that be?

Comment: Did you ask the developers of the program?

Comment: There's no way we could know. Though with some sample output, there's a good chance we could figure it out. Most likely, it's some measure of how much of the program's performance was controlled by CPU performance. (As opposed to I/O, most likely.)

Comment: @Oded: I thought (and was probably right) that asking Stack Overflow would be much faster. :D

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I didn't think of that--that's a great idea! I'd accept your answer if it was one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess: it's calculated as `User time / (System Time + User Time)` ([from here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2380/sysresacctref-6/index.html)) but again: it depends on a program. So if it's low  (0) - on your CPU spends time in kernel space; and if it's high (1) - in the appliactions space.

Comment: Can you explain how you know that?

Comment: @TomAnderson http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2380/sysresacctref-6/index.html . Of course it's only a guess ;)